# How to read and update the lowlimit and highlimit value of lineplot/dataplot?

Tags: dm-script

I try to write a code, that can read change the highlimit value (the highest value of Y axis) of linePlot/dataPlot.  As shown as below,  it is not working. It looks like that we cannot read the high limit value of a line plot by  “number highlimit= imgdisp.linePlotImageDisplaySetContrastLimits(highlimit)”, how can read this value from a lineplot? Thanks

```
number linelen=len(headerline)
        number i, nocommas=0
        for(i=0; i<linelen; i++)
            {
                string thischar=mid(headerline, i, 1)
                if(asc(thischar)==44) nocommas=nocommas+1 // found a comma
            }

        number xsize, ysize
        getsize(array, xsize, ysize)    
        image dataplot=realimage("", 4, xsize,1)
        showimage(dataplot)
        setname(dataplot, imgname)
        imagedisplay imgdisp=dataplot.imagegetimagedisplay(0)               
        number highlimit= imgdisp.linePlotImageDisplaySetContrastLimits(highlimit)
                                if( highlimit<50){imgdisp.linePlotImageDisplaySetContrastLimits( 0, 400)
imgdisp.LinePlotImageDisplaySetDoAutoSurvey( 0, 0 )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things here:

1)

Generally, each "Set" command has an according "Get" command as well. So, the script command to *read* the current display-limits simply is

`linePlotImageDisplayGetContrastLimits()`

2)

Setting contrast limits only works if auto-surveying is switched off. You have to switch it off *before* you set the limits. (If you set the limits first, they are immediately replaced by the values from the survey, so you see no effect.)

3)

I am not sure what you really want to set/get. Do you want to get the maximum *value* of the data, or the display limit?

The maximum value is simply got by `max( )` .

The DisplayLimits define the range on the y-axis, i.e. they set the value you can also specify in the properties of the display as below, they are independent of what values you have in the data:

[image]
Display limits set to 0 - 500. (Maximum data value = 500)

[image]
Display limits set to 0 - 1000. (Maximum data value = 500)

[image]
Display properties dialog.

### Here is some example code of how to set and read the display limits:

```
image spec := RealImage( "", 4, 500 ) 
spec = 20 + random() * icol
spec.ShowImage()

number maxV = max(spec)
imageDisplay LPID = spec.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
LPID.LinePlotImageDisplaySetDoAutoSurvey( 0, 0 )        // switch survey off
LPID.LinePlotImageDisplaySetContrastLimits( 0, maxV*2 ) // Set the display

number lowL, highL
LPID.LinePlotImageDisplayGetContrastLimits( lowL, highL )
Result( "\n Maximum value in data:" + maxV )
Result( "\n Data display range:" + lowL + " to " + highL )
```

Comment: Hi BmyGuest, Thank you so much!  For my purpose, if the max value of data of Y coordinate is smaller than value limit (50), then the display limit of  plot will set 0-500, that lets the readers know the signals are in noise level.  If the max value of data of Y coordinate is larger the value limit (50), the display of the plot will show as "home display". I will use your codes try recoding, thanks again.

Comment: Just let you know, I use your codes and get the result I want. Thanks!